# WFFM 8.1 File Upload validation Control Customisation

Tags: validation, file-upload, sitecore, sitecore8, web-forms-for-marketers

I am using WFFM 8.1 rev. 160304 Update-2.
I have to do below Customisation in File Upload validation Control :

- Max file size should be 2 mb
- File Type Mime type
- File Must upload in Physical Folder .

For top two requirements I am referring the below URLs but it's not working .

https://sitecorejunkie.com/2014/04/06/restrict-certain-files-from-being-attached-to-web-forms-for-marketers-forms-in-sitecore/

https://jonathanrobbins.co.uk/2015/10/06/sitecore-marketplace-module-secure-file-upload/

Comment: What exactly is not working? What have you integrated/tried and what is failing and how?

Comment: Are you using mvc or webforms?

Comment: web Forms For Marketer ..With Sitecore MVC

Comment: @jammykam I am using WFFM 8.1 rev. 160304 Update-2, I uploaded package provided by Jonathanrobbins. and attached "Secure file upload " control in WFFM form, but control itself not rendering.  I am Using Sitecore MVC 8.1 Update 2  with WFFM. 
Using "MVC Form" Rendering to Display the Form.

Answer (score 2):

I have an upload field working with the some of your requirements (file size and extension). It should be extendable to include your others as well.

What we did was:

1. Create a custom field that inherits from `FileUploadField`
2. Add custom attributes to 
   `public override HttpPostedFileBase Value { get; set; }`, e.g. `[LimitAllowedExtensions][LimitFileSize]`
3. Create those custom attributes by overriding from DynamicValidationBase, e.g. `public sealed class LimitAllowedExtensionsAttribute : DynamicValidationBase`
4. In those classes, override `protected override ValidationResult ValidateFieldValue(IViewModel model, object value, ValidationContext validationContext)` with the validation you want

Register your custom field in Sitecore and you're good to go. 
I'm not sure how to do the upload to a physical folder, you might want to look at the other functions in the FileUploadField (and maybe use a decompiler to check out the original code).

Wrote a [blog post](https://ggullentops.blogspot.be/2016/05/sitecore-wffm-mvc-fileuploadfield.html) explaining this.